# Setting up authentication with docker repo via ssh cert for single user

Tags: docker, authentication, ssl

It's possible to authenticate with a docker repo automatically using rsa certificates as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/).

However, this sets up this authentication for all users.  This is a problem because I have personal certificates I want to use to authenticate with from my account only.  If I followed the steps above then anyone who happened to be using the same VM would automatically authenticate with docker as me, which I don't want.

So how can I configure docker so I get the same convenience of automatic authentication with my cert without risking someone else on the machine accidentally using the same certs to authenticate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podman can do this trick: https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-login.1.html

> --cert-dir=path
>
> Use certificates at path (*.crt, *.cert, *.key) to connect to the registry. (Default: /etc/containers/certs.d) Please
> refer to containers-certs.d(5) for details. (This option is not
> available with the remote Podman client, including Mac and Windows
> (excluding WSL2) machines)

```
$ podman login --cert-dir /home/myuser/certs.d/ -u foo -p bar localhost:5000
Login Succeeded!
```

Comment: This implaies I need o manually log into podman every day?   Is there a way to do this so it's automatic?  I could put it in my bashrc, but not if I need a password in the commandline, that doesn't feel secure.  in fact why would it need a password and username, the whole point is to use certs for that.

Comment: “podman login” is basically the same as “docker login” - authentication on a specific registry. You don’t need to login every day, password in the command line is also not necessary. My example shows how to manage certificates, check the documentation for authentication file option if needed.